# Creating an UDP server

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp

I am trying to create an UDP server and client. How can I check if client is "connected" or has disconnected? Since UDP is not really a Connection. How does multiplayer games do it?

Comment: I don't know how multiplayer games do it but if you need to implement certain type of connection over UDP you have to implement your own application layer protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever played a first person game and at some point lost internet connection? You should have gotten a message with a countdown before it automatically disconnects you. Have a look at this picture and notice in the top right the countdown to a timeout.

[image]

UDP maintains the connection by continuously sending and receiving packets. So as an example if for 30 seconds the server hasn't received anything from a client it can presume the client disconnected without  letting the server know (disconnected by timeout).

The implementation is usually quite straightforward: use a timer and reset it each time you receive a packet, if the timer goes over the `TIMEOUT_VALUE` then disconnect this client.